# Is Kendo UI Component is Free for Excel Import/Export?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have tried to use Kendo UI [Component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/) for Import/Export Excel. I go through the website and its paid at all but Kendo-UI for Angular is also available on [Github](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular)

So I am confused that I can use it free or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo UI Core is free, and the full Kendo UI is paid.

As you see on https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison,  Grid and Excel export are not in the free version.

The repository you linked doesn't contain Kendo for Angular, but examples of using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont know why I haven't found this link :D